# Iterate over pre-filtered list of folders

Tags: vbscript, filesystems, wmi

I'm working with a client's flat folder structure that has a single folder containing 45k subfolders with 8-digit folder names, e.g. `51023231`. I have a small script that ripples through them and copies them into a bin-sorted set of subfolders elsewhere on the network (for use with SharePoint), such that the first 5 digits are used as a parent folder, i.e. the contents of `51023231` are copied into `51023\51023231`. It works perfectly well, and I've managed to some modest optimisation when dealing with folders new to the destination.

However, it can take an hour or so to run over the entire 45k set of folders doing folder by folder comparisons, I was wondering if it was possible to run a system-level query to return only an initial list of folders whose modification dates were after a given point, and then run the existing script over that. I've done the usual Google-is-your-friend type trawl, and keep hitting the idea of using WMI to do this, but I don't get much further. Is this because it simply isn't possible with VBScript?

Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with VBScript *using* WMI. It's not something you'd be able to do using the `FileSystemObject`, if that's what you're implying.

You can query WMI's [`Win32_Directory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394130(v=vs.85).aspx) class to filter folders by modified date. The only tricky part is the `datetime` format used by WMI. But the `SWbemDateTime` class can convert a VBScript date to a `datetime` value.

Here's an example:

```
' Create a datetime value for use in our WMI query...
Dim dt
Set dt = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemDateTime")
dt.SetVarDate DateSerial(2015, 8, 31)

Dim objWMI
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")

' Find all subfolders of 'c:\some\path' that were modified > 2015/08/31
Dim objFolders
Set objFolders = objWMI.ExecQuery("select * from Win32_Directory" _
    & " where Drive='C:' and Path='\\some\\path\\' and LastModified>'" & dt & "'")

Dim objFolder
For Each objFolder in objFolders
   WScript.Echo objFolder.Name
Next
```

Comment: Just wondering if this will work for mapped drives as well? The source and destination are both remote, and mapped to L: and P: respectively? I've managed to get the code to work locally, but having little luck with the real data.

Comment: Script worked perfectly! Numpty in charge of Drive lettering to blame! Thanks Bond.